# How best to get map from key list/value list in groovy?

Tags: python, dictionary, groovy

In python, I can do the following:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
d = dict(zip(keys, values))

assert d == {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Is there a nice way to construct a map in groovy, starting from a list of keys and a list of values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
def keys = [1, 2, 3]
def values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def pairs = [keys, values].transpose()

def map = [:]
pairs.each{ k, v -> map[k] = v }
println map
```

Alternatively:

```
def map = [:]
pairs.each{ map << (it as MapEntry) }
```

Comment: Very nice, it looks like `transpose()` is equivalent to python's `zip()`.  Now if only there was a Map constructor for a list of pairs.  `[:].putAll(pairs.collect{ new MapEntry(it[0], it[1]) })` works as a one-liner, but is uglier than I'd like.

Comment: @ataylor See my updated post for another way to use `MapEntry`

Comment: `[keys,values].transpose().inject([:]) { map, it -> map << ( it as MapEntry ) }`

Answer (score 22):

There's also the `collectEntries` function in Groovy 1.8

```
def keys = [1, 2, 3]
def values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[keys,values].transpose().collectEntries { it }
```

Comment: Very nice.  Looking forward to 1.8 even more now.

Comment: You can even leave out the identity closure: `[keys,values].transpose().collectEntries()`

Comment: @Maxy-B yeah, since 1.8.5 :-)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't anything built directly in to groovy, but there are a number of ways to solve it easily, here's one:

```
def zip(keys, values) {
    keys.inject([:]) { m, k -> m[k] = values[m.size()]; m } 
}

def result = zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
assert result == [1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c']
```