# Constructing a map with keys from list A and values from list B

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

I already checked [How best to get map from key list/value list in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877454/how-best-to-get-map-from-key-list-value-list-in-groovy)

and tried the solution given there but in my case, it only gave me a map of size 2, instead of size 6.

In my case listA is: [ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO, PQR]

ListB is: [1,2,1,1,1,1]

```
def pairs = [listA, listB].transpose
def map = [:]
pairs.each{ map << (it as MapEntry) }
println(map)
```

This gives me:

```
[ABC:1, DEF:1]
```

How do I get a map that looks like this:

```
[ABC:1, DEF:2, GHI:1,JKL:1, MNO:1, PQR:1]
```

Comment: Pay more attention to the code, you might do some kind of typo or something. The example you have shown does what you expect - https://gist.github.com/wololock/665d07c0b097b772368d3e9d59f4bf04 (after fixing obvious erros like `.transpose` instead of `.transpose()` etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this to

```
def listA = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']
def listB = [1,2,1,1,1,1]

def map = [listA, listB].transpose().collectEntries()

assert map == [ABC:1, DEF:2, GHI:1,JKL:1, MNO:1, PQR:1]
```

To get a list of entries, it's probably more useful to change this to:

```
def map = [listA, listB].transpose().collect { [id: it[0], num: it[1] as Integer] }
```

Then, the you get the following list:

```
assert map == [
    [id: 'ABC', num:1],
    [id: 'DEF', num:2],
    [id: 'GHI', num:1],
    [id: 'JKL', num:1],
    [id: 'MNO', num:1],
    [id: 'PQR', num:1]
]
```

Comment: I think I know what the problem is in my case. For a map I think the keys have to be unique so if my listA has multiple entries of 'ABC' then the map only uses one of them, what alternative structure can I use that matches two lists of the same size, as in my case a map wouldn't work.

Comment: You could get rid of the collectEntries, and just have a list of pairs

Comment: how would you use the pair, I noticed if I remove the collectEntries, I get a list of lists with each list in list being a combination of a String and an int like this: [['ABC', 1], ['ABC', 2] ...] and so on

Comment: Added an idea to the answer

Answer (score 0):

i run ur code ,but i get the diffrent output whcih is [ABC:1, DEF:2, GHI:1, JKL:1, MNO:1, PQR:1] (i use [webconsole](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/))

```
def listA = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']
def listB = [1,2,1,1,1,1]

def pairs = [listA, listB].transpose()
def map = [:]
pairs.each{ map << (it as MapEntry) }
println(map)
```